# Unable to translate the LINQ expression while using Group by

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an Asp.net core web API that uses EF Core DB first approach. I have the following Tables in my SQL server database.

- Application table - contains a list of Applications.
- Role table - contains a list of Roles (user, admin, Super Admin, etc.)
- User table - contains a list of Users
- User Role table - contains a mapping between User and Role table
- Feature tables - contains a list of Features (Home page, user management, etc.)
- RoleFeature table - contains the mapping between Feature and Role table

I am trying to get the RoleName and list of features for the given UserId and appId.

Below is the Linq query I have so far:

```
RoleDto role = 
    from a in ctx.Application.Where(x => x.ApplicationId == appId)
    from r in ctx.Role.Where(x => x.ApplicationId == a.ApplicationId)
    from ur in ctx.UserRole.Where(x => x.UserId == userId && x.RoleId == r.RoleId)
    from rf in ctx.RoleFeature.Where(x => x.RoleId == ur.RoleId)
    from f in ctx.Feature.Where(x => x.FeatureId == rf.FeatureId).Where(x => x.IsActive)
    group new { r.RoleName, f.FeatureId } by ur.RoleId into g
    select new RoleDto
    {
        Name = g.Select(x => x.RoleName).FirstOrDefault(),
        FeatureIds = g.Select(x => x.FeatureId).ToList()
    }.AsNoTracking()
```

However, I am getting an error saying unable to translate the LINQ expression.

Comment: See the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client),and use `AsEnumerable` and `ToList`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to select the `Application`. You can start by selecting `Role` directly as -

```
from r in dbCtx.Role.Where(x => x.ApplicationId == appId)
```

This will simplify the final SQL generated by EF. So the query will be faster.

2. If a `User` has multiple `Role` then you are trying to take the first one. You should do that when you are selecting `Role` as -

```
from r in ctx.Role.Where(x => x.ApplicationId == a.ApplicationId).Take(1)
```

3. Finally, you can fetch a list of `RoleName` and `FeatureId`, and then do the grouping on client side -

```
var query =
    from r in dbCtx.Role.Where(x => x.ApplicationId == appId).Take(1)
    from ur in dbCtx.UserRole.Where(x => x.UserId == userId && x.RoleId == r.RoleId)
    from rf in dbCtx.RoleFeature.Where(x => x.RoleId == ur.RoleId && x.Feature.IsActive)
    select new
    {
        RoleName = rf.Role.RoleName,
        FeatureId = rf.FeatureId
    };

var roleDto = query.AsNoTracking()
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(p => p.RoleName)
    .Select(g => new RoleDto
    {
        Name = g.Key,
        FeatureIds = g.Select(p => p.FeatureId).ToList()
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the *FirstOrDefault()* in the select section of the "groupby" query.

You are probably using ef core version higher than 2.1 and there are some changes in handling *groupby* query. You should take a look at the following link :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#linq-groupby-translation

> Before version 2.1, in EF Core the GroupBy LINQ operator would always
> be evaluated in memory. We now support translating it to the SQL GROUP
> BY clause in most common cases.

So the query should be translated to SQL GROUP BY, but methods such as FirstOrDefault() can not be translated. As a fast solution you can change FirstOrDefault() with Max(), Min() or other aggregate functions that are supported in DB.

Comment: I tried commenting out the statement `Name = g.Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault(),`. I am still getting the same error. I am using .net core 3.1

Comment: What about FeatureIds? could you try commenting that as well? my guess is that the problem is with the GroupBy, as it has changed fundamentally in EfCore recently. I think you can only have aggregate functions in select section of a groupBy.